# ConsoleTraceListener: Don't write to VS output window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, logging, trace

I have a trace lister (DefaultTraceListener derived) to write a special format to the VS output window (so double click -> go to source works).  I remove the standard VS output default trace listener and replace it with this one.
But I don't want this long format showing in my console so I have a separate ConsoleTraceLister derived listener to give a shorter version there.  The issue is this also writes to VS output so in that window traces are doubled up.
**How to stop a ConsoleTraceLister derived listener from writing to VS output window?**

Comment: Remove the default trace listener, either by .config or explicitly in code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry I should have mention I have already removed the default trace listener.  The issue is that the my console trace listener ALSO writes to VS output window.  Ive updated the question to clarify.

Comment: What's with the *separate listener*?  A simple way to stop this is to untick the hosting process in the Project + Properties, Debug tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//here is somthing you can try not sure if it will help

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;


public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TextWriterTraceListener myWriter = new
        TextWriterTraceListener(System.Console.Out);
        Debug.Listeners.Add(myWriter);
        Debug.WriteLine("Test output 1 ");
        Stream myFile = File.Create("output.txt");
        TextWriterTraceListener myTextListener = new
        TextWriterTraceListener(myFile);
        Debug.Listeners.Add(myTextListener);
        Debug.WriteLine("Test output 2 ");


        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("Demo"))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("Demo", "Demo");
        }


        Debug.Listeners.Add(new EventLogTraceListener("Demo"));
        Debug.WriteLine("Test output 3 ");
        myWriter.Flush();
        myWriter.Close();
        myFile.Flush();
        myFile.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked - Ive edited your answer to clarify the solution - I hope thats ok.  Cheers.

Comment: Not a problem I am glad that I could help